# Loss function calculation in "Multiple Object Recognition with Visual Attention"

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, recurrent-neural-network

In the paper [Multiple Object Recognition with Visual Attention](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7755) the author has described a way to calculate loss function using REINFORCE algorithm. Could anybody explain how to empirically calculate loss given the following inputs:

```
L = [l1,l2,l3, ..., ln]

y_pred = [y'1,y'2,y'3,...., y'n]

y_true = [y1,y2,y3,...., yn]
```

Comment: I got the idea from this lecture 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHZVXao4qXs' . thanks for not responding it :)